# Are these two combinators already available in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, boolean, combinators

I need binary combinators of the type

```
(a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
```

or maybe

```
[a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
```

(though this would just be the foldr1 of the first, and I usually only need to combine two boolean functions.)

Are these built-in?

---

If not, the implementation is simple:

```
both f g x = f x && g x
either f g x = f x || g x
```

or perhaps

```
allF fs x = foldr (\ f b -> b && f x) True fs
anyF fs x = foldr (\ f b -> b || f x) False fs
```

Hoogle turns up nothing, but sometimes its search doesn't generalise properly. Any idea if these are built-in? Can they be built from pieces of an existing library?

If these aren't built-in, you might suggest new names, because these names are pretty bad. In fact that's the main reason I hope that they *are* built-in.

Comment: `either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c` is already in `Prelude`; choose a different name?

Comment: I know, that's why I hoped that somebody could suggest nice alternatives.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Control.Monad` defines an `instance Monad ((->) r)`, so

```
ghci> :m Control.Monad
ghci> :t liftM2 (&&)
liftM2 (&&) :: (Monad m) => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool
ghci> liftM2 (&&) (5 <) (< 10) 8
True
```

You could do the same with `Control.Applicative.liftA2`.

---

Not to seriously suggest it, but...

```
ghci> :t (. flip ($)) . flip all
(. flip ($)) . flip all :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
ghci> :t (. flip ($)) . flip any
(. flip ($)) . flip any :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that instance. So I didn't even try `liftM2 (&&)`.

Comment: @ephemient: how about `fmap and . sequence`?

Comment: I think I would go with Monoid (`Any` and `All`, specifically) and `mconcat`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a builtin, but the alternative I prefer is to use type classes to **generalize
the Boolean operations to predicates of any arity:**

```
module Pred2 where

class Predicate a where
  complement :: a -> a
  disjoin    :: a -> a -> a
  conjoin    :: a -> a -> a

instance Predicate Bool where
  complement = not
  disjoin    = (||)
  conjoin    = (&&)

instance (Predicate b) => Predicate (a -> b) where
  complement = (complement .)
  disjoin f g x = f x `disjoin` g x
  conjoin f g x = f x `conjoin` g x


-- examples:

ge :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
ge = complement (<)

pos = (>0)
nonzero = pos `disjoin` (pos . negate)
zero    = complement pos `conjoin` complement (pos . negate)
```

I love Haskell!

Comment: Ooh, nice, though the error messages if you ever accidentally mix arities may be *interesting*.  I would actually lean towards calling these `.&&. .||.` or something like that :-)

Comment: This is really cool. Glad I stumbled across this! Haskell never ceases to amaze :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't know builtins, but I like the names you propose.

```
getCoolNumbers = filter $ either even (< 42)
```

Alternately, one could think of an operator symbol in addition to typeclasses for alternatives.

```
getCoolNumbers = filter $ even <|> (< 42)
```

Comment: The reason I don't like `either` is because of `Prelude.either` aka `Data.Either.either`. Besides already being used, I like them too. :)

Comment: About the operator: <&&> is unused and <||> only by Parsec (according to hoogle). So those are probably the best alternatives.